# How to make Powershell to output the result to a csv

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, psobject

I am trying to output to a csv file the result that I am getting from "Get-ChildItem"
I need to save only the LastWriteTime and the Name.

[This is the Get-ChildItem output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o0LY.png)

I am trying something like

```
    $pc = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path S:\Docker\RCT\repo\*xml -Recurse -Force 
    
    $DeviceObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        DeviceName = $pc.Name
                        FileName = $file.Name
                        FileDate = $file.LastWriteTime
                    }
    $DeviceObjList += $DeviceObj
    $DeviceObjList | Export-Csv -Path "$current_path\FileStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

But my csv is not saving the file name and also the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ForEach-Object` to loop though your $file object

```
$pc = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path S:\Docker\RCT\repo\*xml -Recurse -Force 
$file | ForEach-Object {
    $DeviceObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    DeviceName = $pc.Name
                    FileName = $_.Name
                    FileDate = $_.LastWriteTime
                }
    $DeviceObjList += $DeviceObj
}
$DeviceObjList | Export-Csv -Path "$current_path\FileStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

..but in fact, this is more efficient:

```
$pc = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path S:\Docker\RCT\repo\*xml -Recurse -Force 
$DeviceObjList = $file | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        DeviceName = $pc.Name
        FileName = $_.Name
        FileDate = $_.LastWriteTime
    }
}
$DeviceObjList | Export-Csv -Path "$current_path\FileStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally I could output everything

Answer (score 0):

1. You Don't need WMI to get the computer name, use the built-in variable `$env:COMPUTERNAME`
2. Use [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=These%20parameters%20can%20be%20used,value%2C%20and%20optional%20formatting%20information.) to add the Computer name to the results.
3. Iteration not required here, just add the `Export-Csv` to the pipeline

So you can do that:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path S:\Docker\RCT\repo\*xml -Recurse -Force 
$File | Select @{N="DeviceName";E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},Name,LastWriteTime | 
Export-Csv -Path "$current_path\FileStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

And if you want to make it shorter, you can use aliases and don't define any variables

```
gci S:\Docker\RCT\repo\*xml -R -Fo | 
select @{N="DeviceName";E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},Name,LastWriteTime | 
epcsv "$current_path\FileStatus.csv" -NoT -En UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
But I was using the WMI because the idea is to improve the script later to get the information from remote PC.
But with your help, I could improve a lot.

Comment: if the answer is helpful however, you should vote it up!